# Calculate the value of the expression after the join of the tables in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2012

**Table structure**

[image]

**Goal:**

Is to calculate the value of the expression(They are the column names from the table).

Check whether the expression is correct and evaluate the result.
Expected and Actual results : Unable to evaluate the expression value with the help of `SSIS`. Failing at validation level when used in a query at OLE db source level.

Unable to get the value of expression at the granularity shown using `SSIS` components.

Trying to check by row by row debugging to flag the error expression value as bad. Trying not to run this in a batch. Looking to run it row by row to segregate the error rows.

Comment: looks like a simple join between 2 tables.. what have you tried so far to get your desired results?

Answer (score 0):

`Dynamic SQL` will solve your problem.

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(ColA INT,ColB VARCHAR(20),ColC INT,ColE INT)
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA VALUES(1,'US',2,1)
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA VALUES(1,'US',4,2)
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA VALUES(2,'IND',3,6)
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA VALUES(2,'IND',1,5)

CREATE TABLE TableB(ColX INT,ColY VARCHAR(20),ColZ VARCHAR(20),ColV VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB VALUES(1,'US','ColC*ColE','Table1')
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB VALUES(2,'US','ColC/ColE','Table1')
```

**Dynamic SQL Query:**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

SELECT @query = @query + '
UNION
SELECT A.ColA,
    A.ColB,
    A.ColC,
    A.ColE,
    B.ColZ AS ColF, 
     1.0*' +ColZ+ ' 
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B ON A.ColA = B.ColX
WHERE ColZ = ''' + ColZ + ''' '
FROM TableB;

SET @query = STUFF(@query,1,6,'');

--SELECT @query
--Print @query

EXEC (@query)
```

Check the output in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d09b9/11)